# Does POSIX standardize the file descriptor numbers?

Tags: c, posix, file-descriptors, standard

Does POSIX mandate that `stdin` is 0, `stdout` is 1 and `stderr` is 2 or is this only a convention? Do other systems diverge from that convention or is it a safe assumption?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems that they are standardized in the POSIX spec,

- [POSIX.1-2017](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) by proxy of [unistd.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html)

  > The  header shall define the following symbolic constants for file streams:
  >
  > - `STDERR_FILENO` File number of stderr; 2.
  > - `STDIN_FILENO` File number of stdin; 0.
  > - `STDOUT_FILENO` File number of stdout; 1.
- But also the [POSIX docs on "`stderr`, `stdin`, `stdout` - standard I/O streams"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stdin.html) state,

  > This volume of POSIX.1-2017 defers to the ISO C standard.
- The [ISO ISO/IEC 9899:201x Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) state only,

  > The three predefined streams stdin, stdout, and stderr are unoriented at program startup.

It seems ISO C is relatively mute on this allowing the kernel to assign whatever it wants to the descriptors known as `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, and `STDIN`. But that the POSIX docs on `unistd.h` are explicit about what they should resolve to at that level.

## Other Operating Systems

- [Microsoft Windows follows the POISX convention in the "Low Level I/O" interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/low-level-i-o)

Comment: Almost anything hosted that's ANSI C compliant will usually follow the same convention.  This includes pretty much everything that is an actual operating system (instead of something that's just some bare-bones libraries, like an Arduino for example).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn: That's not quite true, because the functions that take/return file descriptors (`open()`, `close()`, `read()`, `write()` etc.) are part of POSIX but not part of ANSI C - the C equivalents are `fopen()`, `fwrite()` etc. That said, the vast majority of ANSI C systems that people are likely to encounter commonly are either Unix-like or Windows-like, so in practice what you say is generally true :)

Answer (score 2):

[The POSIX Specification for Shell Command Language, Section 2.7, Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07), says

> The overall format used for redirection is:
>    [*n*‪] *redir-op word*
>
> The number *n* is an optional decimal number
>   designating the file descriptor number; …
>       ︙
>   …  The values 0, 1, and 2 have special meaning and conventional uses
>   and are implied by certain redirection operations;
>   they are referred to as *standard input*, *standard output*,
>   and *standard error*, respectively.  …
>
> ︙
>
> The general format for redirecting input is:
>    [*n* ]<*word*
>
> where the optional *n* represents the file descriptor number. 
>   If the number is omitted,
>   the redirection shall refer to standard input (file descriptor 0).

… and a similar paragraph saying that `>` is equivalent to `1>`,
referring to standard output.